# How do I pass in a list as an argument with defun in LISP? (recursively)

Tags: recursion, lisp

My code below is suppose to add numbers `@n` til `20` to `@myList`. I am trying to pass in a list as an argument in a recursive function, but my syntax is incorrect. How would I do this?

Note: I believe I am using append incorrectly as well.

```
;Add numbers from @n til 20 to @myList
(defun someFunction(myList, n)
    (if (= n 20) ;Base case, return 20
        20
    )
    (append myList n) ;Append n to the end of myList
    (someFunction myList (+ n 1))
)
```

Comment: What use is the comma `,`? Does it make sense in Lisp? You have an IF construct, but you don't use its value - why? As it is now, you can remove the `IF` form and it will make no difference.

Comment: It looks like you should review some basic Lisp. Don't assume that Lisp is anything like those other languages you've used. (The more you can forget about them, the better.)

Answer (score 1):

While not the answer to your exact question about where the mistake is, why not something like:

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
(defun some-function (list start end)
  (append list (alexandria:iota (- (1+ end) start) :start start)))
```